# Loading Executable from ASP.NET Web Page very slow in AZURE

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, azure, console

I have been at this for a few days now. I have a windows executable that I wrote that does some hardcore GDI+ stuff with System.Drawing, etc. It spits out a PDF File. This intense process takes 3.5 seconds when running from Console. However, when using the following code, the same process takes 15-30 seconds for the user to get the PDF.

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    processInfo.FileName = fullExePath;
    processInfo.Arguments = a; // args[0] + " " + args[1] + " " + args[2] + " " + args[3] + " " + args[4] + " " + args[5] + " " + args[6] + " " + PageTitle + " " + args[8] + " " + args[9] + " " + args[10];
    processInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fullExePath);
    processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processInfo);

    // Do not wait for the child process to exit before reading to the end of its redirected stream. Read the output stream first and then wait.                        
    output += p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();
```

Process writes PDF to filesystem in predetermined location.. then

```
System.IO.FileInfo f = new System.IO.FileInfo(OutputFilePath);

long fileSize = f.Length;
System.Web.HttpResponse response1 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response1.Clear();
response1.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
response1.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("{0}; filename={1}; size={2}", ContentDisposition, ReturnFileName, fileSize.ToString()));
response1.BinaryWrite(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(OutputFilePath));
```

I don't know where the extra 10-20 seconds are coming from. Its a 64 bit server..

Tried:
Compiling as 32bit, Using Admin User (process fails to start), process explorer, running from console

Comment: Have you tried adding breakpoints to the above code to find the bottleneck?

Comment: I have tried breakpoints, process explorer, system diagnostic, etc. There seems to be a 14 second delay when spanwning child exe threads from main exe

Comment: What types of VM do you have, an XS or larger?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem - I have an Azure Website running in an S3-sized App Service Plan (4 cores, 7GB RAM) and starting another process takes much longer than when run locally or on a traditional server or VM. It's really damaging the user-experience because prior to moving to Azure the results were near-instant (about 200ms in total) - now they're over 1000ms - very unacceptable.